# Welch method implementation not smooth

Tags: fft, window-functions, scipy

I have been trying to recreate the welch method implemented in scipy.signal by hand but my results don't look close enough in my opinion. How come the scipy.signal.welch method is displaying much smoother results although the settings appear to be th same? What am I missing in my code?

Here is the difference:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from scipy.fft import rfft, fftfreq
from scipy.signal import get_window, welch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
def getAmps(fres,fList,fft_data):
    amplitudes=[]
           
    for f in fList:
        idx = int(f/fres)
        amplitudes.append(fft_data[idx])
        
    return np.array(amplitudes)
 
#Load Data
file_path = '../Wavs/pinknoisemono.wav'
fs, data = wav.read(file_path)
 
#FFT Setup
fft_size = 4096
numSamples = len(data)
 
myf = np.fft.rfftfreq(fft_size, 1.0/fs)[:-1]
 
window_length = fft_size
hop_size = window_length
window = 'boxcar'
window_func = get_window(window, Nx = window_length)
 
complexData_list = []
 
complexData = None
 
#Windowing
numSeg = 0
for i in range(0, numSamples - window_length, hop_size):
    windowed_signal = data[i:i + window_length] * window_func
 
    spectrum = rfft(windowed_signal, n = fft_size * 7)
        
    complexData = getAmps(fs/fft_size, myf, spectrum)
    
    complexData_list.append(complexData)
 
    numSeg+=1
 
#Averaging and scaling
#amp including scaling like in scipy.signal.welch according to window power
myamps = (abs(np.mean(complexData_list,axis=0))**2)
myamps_scaled = myamps / (fs*(np.sum(window_func**2))/fft_size)
 
#Welch Computation
f, welchamps = welch(data, fs,window, scaling='spectrum',nperseg=fft_size, noverlap=0)
 
#Compare
plt.loglog(myf,myamps_scaled)
plt.loglog(f,welchamps)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> myamps = (abs(np.mean(complexData_list,axis=0))**2)

Looks like the order of operation here is wrong. You should FIRST calculate the magnitude squared and then take the mean. The PSD is the average of the energies, not the energy of the averages.